# Drilldown event in Highcharts column chart

Tags: highcharts

[In this Highcharts column chart](https://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-drilldown) the user can drill down by clicking on the column.

This works fine, however all the data, including the data of the drilled column, needs to be available when the chart is firstly created.

What I need is to capture the drilldown event click and populate the chart with that information, sending the data only when the user clicked on a specific column. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible and simple. You need to use `drilldown` event callback function, call API request in it and use `addSeriesAsDrilldown` method - as in the example below:

```
    chart: {
        type: 'column',
        events: {
            drilldown: function(e) {
                if (!e.seriesOptions) {

                    var chart = this,
                        drilldowns = {
                            ...
                        },
                        series = drilldowns[e.point.name];

                    // Show the loading label
                    chart.showLoading('Simulating Ajax ...');

                    setTimeout(function() {
                        chart.hideLoading();
                        chart.addSeriesAsDrilldown(e.point, series);
                    }, 1000);
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/e9m74kgp/

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.drilldown

https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart#addSeriesAsDrilldown